# Using Maclaurin Series to estimate values $f(-0.1)$

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series

> Using Maclaurin series of the hyperbolic sine function, $\sinh (x) $

Given $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ....+ \frac{x^n}{n!}+ ....$,

$e^{-x} = 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n!}$

$\sinh (x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} (1+(x-x) + x^2)$

My first 3 terms are wrong. It is supposed to be $\frac{1}{2} (2x + 2(\frac{x^2}{2!}) + 2(\frac{x^5}{5!})) + .... \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$

where did I go wrong? Im just following the power/taylor series of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ given above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, we have the MacLaurin series for the exponential function $e^{x}$:
\begin{align*}
e^{x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4}}{4!} + \frac{x^{5}}{5!} + \ldots
\end{align*}
On the other hand, we have the MacLaurin series for the exponential function $e^{-x}$:
\begin{align*}
e^{-x} = 1 - x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} - \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4}}{4!} - \frac{x^{5}}{5!} + \ldots
\end{align*}

Hence we obtain the desired expression:
\begin{align*}
\sinh(x) & = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1 - 1) + (x - (-x)) + \left(\frac{x^{2}}{2!} - \frac{x^{2}}{2!}\right) + \left(\frac{x^{3}}{3!} - \left(-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}\right)\right) + \ldots\right]\\\\
& = x + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{5}}{5!} + \frac{x^{7}}{7!} + \ldots
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!